# How to deal with "." in Field Name Postgresql (periscope)

Tags: postgresql

i am a newwbie to dbs sql postgres ^^
but i manage to do the basic queries

Now i struggle to query for a field that has this kind of name
eg.:
via.channel

i tried "", [] and any other way of escaping it but it doenst work.

Please Advice!

eg.

```
select via.channel
from my_database.channel
limit 10
```

Comment: Is the column actually called `via.channel`? Or did you copy the query from some other query?

Comment: What is the error message? What do you get for `SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name LIKE '%channel%';`?

Comment: Double quotes `"` are the correct way to deal with such a name: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS  if that doesn't work, then please **[edit]** your question and add the statement you tried.

Comment: yes its actally called like that, but i might be wrong, is there another way to verify it, via a query or sth?
its seems like i have to UNNEST this when i query for it. it might be an array thats why

does that make sense to you? you got anything i can read about how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this -

```
SELECT "via.channel"
FROM my_database.channel
LIMIT 10
```

It is recommended, using naming convention for columns in Postgres.
https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acreldb/p1iw263fz6wvnbn1d6nyw71a9sf2.htm

It would be simple if there are not much dependencies on this column apart from select queries, use via_channel or something.